# Map Map.lookup to list

Tags: haskell

I have the Data.Map (freqMap) which looks like:

```
"SO" -> "10"
"OM" -> "20"
...
```

so every two letters I map some value.

And I have a list of strings:

```
["SO", "OM", "ME", "ET" ...]
```

I need to transform this list to another list:

```
["10", 20", ...]
```

where every element is a value from my Map (freqMap).

I have created solution using recursion:

```
score_ngram :: [String] -> Map.Map String String -> [Int] -> [Int]
score_ngram [] scores result = result
score_ngram ngrams scores result = score_ngram (tail ngrams) scores (result ++ [value])
    where value = case (Map.lookup (head ngrams) scores) of
        Just v -> read v :: Int
        Nothing -> 0
```

But i'm just wondering if it is possible to get it using map function ?

Something like this:

```
map (Map.lookup element_of_list freqMap) ["SO", "OM", "ME", "ET" ...]
```

Comment: Your `map` example almost works, you just need to make it a function: `map (\elem_of_list -> Map.lookup elem_of_list freqMap) ["SO",...]`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you store the values in the map as `String` if you're just going to read them out as `Int` anyway?

Comment: No, there is not reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want a score of 0 for nonexistent ngrams, you can use:

```
map (read . flip (Map.findWithDefault "0") freqMap) ["SO", "OM", "ME", "ET" ...]
```